# Laravel - Auth::attempt does not return correct response

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my login controller. Like this it does not work:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Account;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = array(
            'email'=> $request->email,
            'password'=> hash('sha512', $request->password)
        );

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            echo "Login is valid";
        } else {
            echo "IT is not valid login!";
        }

        var_dump($credentials);


    }
}
```

However like this it works:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Account;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = array(
            'email'=> $request->email,
            'password'=> hash('sha512', $request->password)
        );

        if (Account::where($credentials)) {
            echo "Login is valid";
        } else {
            echo "IT is not valid login!";
        }

        var_dump($credentials);


    }
}
```

Here is how I create the account:

```
    $account = new Account();
    $account->email = $request->email;
    $account->password = hash('sha512', $request->password);
    $account->name = $request->firstName;
    $account->lastname = $request->lastName;
    $account->country = $request->country;
    $account->dob_day = $request->dobDay;
    $account->dob_month = $request->dobMonth;
    $account->dob_year = $request->dobYear;
    $account->save();
```

Here is my auth.php config file: https://pastebin.com/VqPCNsYC

Why `Auth::attempt` is not returning correct response?
I am sure data is given and hashed correctly because of `Account::where($credentials)` this check returns `Login is valid`.

I am new to Laravel. Can you help me out?

Comment: I believe you need to pass the unhashed password to Auth::attempt

Comment: `Auth::attempt` will hash and match the password itself, you don't need to hash the password.

Comment: Tried but not working. My password is stored with sha512 hashing. Tried what you both suggested but it does not work in that way either.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO there is a bit of confusion in your code:

1) `Account::where($credentials)` is always true because it returns an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` so you always get `"Login is valid"` with every input you have.

2) `Auth::attempt($credentials)` does not attempt to retrieve the `User` with all the credentials provided but it explicit **removes** the `password` key from the `where` it uses to get the `User` model (you can see that in the `retrieveByCredentials()` function in `Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider`). After it has retrieved the `User` it checks that the password provided in the login input matches the hash of the password it has stored in the database.

3) You don't need to hash the password, it is not used to retrieve the user as per point 2 (BTW each time you `hash` a password the *hash* is different so you cannot use it in a `where` like you tried), so you have to write this:

```php
$credentials = array(
            'email'=> $request->email,
            'password'=> $request->password
        );
```

4) Laravel does not use `hash('512',..)` to hash a password in the `register` controller, the supported driver for hashing are; `bcrypt`, `argon`, `argon2id`, and you can change it in `config/hashing.php`. Laravel uses `Hash::make()` in the register controller, if you have changed this good luck, you have to change also the way the provider checks the password (see `Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider`). But this should be another question.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To compare a password against the one stored in the database (a hashed one) you don't need to hash it. Just use the un-hashed version of the password:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = array(
        'email'=> $request->email,
        'password'=> $request->password, // <----
    );

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        echo "Login is valid";
    } else {
        echo "IT is not valid login!";
    }

    var_dump($credentials);
}
```

Under the hood Laravel will hash the password and compare it against the ones in the database.

Comment: Tried to pass it not hashed but it does not work again.

Answer (score 0):

According to the  [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication)
you need to provides the simple password only in the validation.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Handle an authentication attempt.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');



if (Account::where($credentials)) {
        echo "Login is valid";
    } else {
        echo "IT is not valid login!";
    }

    var_dump($credentials);
}
```

Now it will provide you the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is echo (echo will not stop the rest of code execution).

---

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = array(
        'email'=> $request->email,
        'password'=> $request->password
    );

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        dd("Login is valid"); // use return or dd instead of echo "Login is valid" (it will work with exit like echo('msg'); exit;)
    } else {
        dd("IT is not valid login!");
    }
    var_dump($credentials);
}
```

---